# LocalStorage of contenteditable content (AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, angularjs-directive, web-storage

I have a little AngularJS tool that inserts cards. **My goal is to store them locally. I worked that out for the cards array, but not for the card content, that is "contenteditable"
Can u help me with this and give me some best practice solutions?**

Here's a Plunker (in JS) for that (the red big button deletes the localStorage. Be sure to have a wide window open): http://plnkr.co/edit/SlbWZ5Bh62MDKWViUsMr

This is my code (with CoffeeScript. For JS see the Plunker above):

**This is the markup for the user input**

```
<div class="card card-{{ card.color }}">
    <header>
        <p class="points" contenteditable></p>
        <p class="number" contenteditable>#</p>
        <h2 class="customerName"  contenteditable>{{ card.customer.name }}</h2>
        <h3 class="projectName" contenteditable>Project Name</h3>
    </header>
    <article>
        <h1 class="task" contenteditable>Title</h1>
        <p class="story" contenteditable>Description</p>
    </article>
    <footer>
        <div class="divisions">
        <p class="division"></p>
        <button ng-click="deleteCard()" class="delete">X</button>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
<div class="card card-{{ card.color }} backside">
    <article>
        <h2 class="requirement">Requirements</h2>
        <p contenteditable></p>
    </article>
</div>
```

**Here you see my localStorage setup for the cards array that was in my controller above:**

```
Card = (@color, @customer) ->

        $scope.cards = []

        json = localStorage.getItem "cards"
        getCards = JSON.parse(json) if json?
        $scope.cards = $scope.cards.concat getCards if getCards?

        $scope.reset = ->
            localStorage.clear()

        $scope.save = ->
            cards = []
            for card in $scope.cards
                cards.push
                    color: card.color
                    customer:
                        name: card.customer.name

            localStorage.setItem "cards", JSON.stringify(cards)

        $scope.addCardRed = (customer) ->
            $scope.cards.push new Card("red", customer)
            $scope.save()
```

**How do I store the user inputs in the different fields in localStorage? I heards something about serialization, but I don't know what it means in my case!**

**Thank you so much in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ng-model` directive with any `contenteditable` field, just like you would do with an input or textarea.  so, instead of trying to use the `{{...}}` braces to bind your model to your view, you should just use `ng-model`, and then just treat your editable DOM elements as if they were fields in a form.

For example, in your view :

```
<header ng-repeat="card in cards">
    <!-- These are just sample fields for the card object, but you can modify them -->
    <p class="points" contenteditable ng-model="card.points"></p>
    <p class="number" contenteditable ng-model="card.number"></p>
    <h2 class="customerName"  contenteditable ng-model="card.customer.name"></h2>
    <h3 class="projectName" contenteditable ng-model="card.projectName"></h3>
</header>
```

And then in your controller you would attach the model to the `$scope` as you've already done using `$scope.cards = $scope.cards.concat getCards if getCards?`.  This will two-way bind your `cards` model to your controller's scope.

And then in your controller, to mirror the model data in `LocalStorage`, you can do it yourself using something like this:

In your controller:

```
....
//  for example's sake
$scope.cards = [  // the cards array would look something like this
    {points: 0, number: 5, customer: {name: 'bob'}, projectName: 'myProj1'},
    {points: 1, number: 6, customer: {name: 'joe'}, projectName: 'myProj2'},
    {points: 2, number: 7, customer: {name: 'bill'}, projectName: 'myProj3'},
    {points: 3, number: 8, customer: {name: 'jerry'}, projectName: 'myProj4'}
];
....
// listen to all changes to the $scope.cards array
$scope.$watch('cards', function(newVal){
    var str = angular.toJson(newVal); // serialize the cards array into a string
    // NOTE: the 'someKey' string is the key that you'll use later to retrieve it back
    window.localStorage['someKey'] = str;  // store the serialized string in localStorage
}, true);
....
```

In the above example, the `angular.toJson(newVal)` will take the `newVal` variable (which is just a reference to the "recently updated" cards array), and will serialize it into  JSON string (ie `angular.toJson` just basically wraps the native `JSON.stringify()` method).  In order to put a javascript object into `LocalStorage` it must be serialized to a string because you can only put primitives as the value in a `LocalStorage` key.

So the `newVal` will get put into `localStorage` looking something like this:

```
"[{"points":0,"number":5,"customer":{"name":"bob"},"projectName":"myProj1"},{"points":1,"number":6,"customer":{"name":"joe"},"projectName":"myProj2"},{"points":2,"number":7,"customer":{"name":"bill"},"projectName":"myProj3"},{"points":3,"number":8,"customer":{"name":"jerry"},"projectName":"myProj4"}]"
```

And then later (whenever you need it) you can retrieve the `cards` array from `localStorage` again using the following:

```
var str = window.localStorage['someKey'];
$scope.cards = angular.fromJson(str);
```

Or you can use a library to do the serialization/saving like this one: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage.  I've never used it but it does exactly what you want it to.

Hopefully that helps clarify things a bit.

UPDATE:  This is beyond the scope of this question, but since you asked.  It sounds like your'e not grasping the concept of the `ng-repeat` and `ng-model` directives.  These are probably the two most famous (and most widely used) directives in Angular.  By combining these two directives (as in the view example above), it will automatically keep your model (ie `$scope.cards`) and your view (ie `<header>`) in sync as users edit the data in your view.  `ng-repeat` will "automagically" create a new header element for every `card` in your `cards` array (hence the `ng-repeat="card in cards"`).  So as new cards get added or cards are removed from the cards array, Angular will add or remove `<header>` elements as needed.  Then, using the `contenteditable` and `ng-model` directives, Angular will bind the content of those editable DOM elements to the values for each card.  Typically `ng-model` is used with form elements (ie inputs/textareas/selects) but it can also be used for any editable field.  Think of your editable elements as if they were an input, and then take a good long look at the `<input ng-model="" />` example from the angular docs [found here](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3ainput).  That should help.

Comment: I am still unsure how to implement it. Can you give me another hint? Do I have to attach the models in the Card object or outside? Could you give me an example how I store my contenteditable content? Somehow, I haven't fully understood how the whole localStorage and serialization stuff works :-/ I would be very grateful if you'd help me! Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: I added a lot more explanation to make my previous answer a lot more verbose.  Let me know if you're still confused.

Comment: You are awesome! Thanks for your new reply. Now I understood a lot better. What still causes headaches is how to use the cards array propery, since some data are already there, when I add a new card, and some data of the cards array get added after the user put something in. Also, the cards array (how you filled it above) is empty in the first place, right? How does my empty card array play together with already set values like customer? 

At least I understand the $watch and storing thing, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Now I know what confused me!

The Two-Way-Binding of my card properties didn't work with contenteditable. I removed each contenteditable attribute and instead of p, h2 and so on I replaced the tags with input tags. That worked fine for me.

**Thank you for your patience and your great explanations, @tennisagent! And for the $watch hint! I am really grateful for your help :)**

**That's my solution for the Controller:**

```
angular.controller 'CustomerController', ($scope)   ->

    $scope.customers = [
        { name: "name1" }
        { name: "name2" }
        { name: "name3" }
    ]

    $scope.cards = []

    Card = (@color, @customer, @points, @number, @projectName, @story) ->

    $scope.$watch 'cards', ((newValue) ->
        string = angular.toJson(newValue)
        localStorage["cards"] = string
    ), true

    json = localStorage["cards"]
    parsedCards = angular.fromJson(json) if json?
    $scope.cards = $scope.cards.concat parsedCards if parsedCards?


    $scope.reset = ->
        localStorage.clear()
        sessionStorage.clear()

        $scope.cards = []

    $scope.addCardRed = (customer) ->
        $scope.cards.push new Card("red", customer)
```

**That's my solution for the Markup:**

```
<div class="card card-{{ card.color }}">
    <header>
        <input class="points" contenteditable ng-model="card.points"></input>
        <input class="number" placeholder="#" contenteditable ng-model="card.number"></input>
        <input class="customerName"  contenteditable ng-model="card.customer.name"></input>
        <input class="projectName" placeholder="Projekt" contenteditable ng-model="card.projectName"></input>
    </header>
    <article>
        <input class="task" placeholder="Titel" contenteditable ng-model="card.task"></input>
        <textarea class="story" placeholder="Story" contenteditable ng-model="card.story"></textarea>
    </article>
    <footer>
        <div class="divisions">
            <p class="division"></p>
            <button ng-click="deleteCard()" class="delete">X</button>
        </div>
    </footer>
</div>
<div class="card card-{{ card.color }} backside">
    <article>
        <h2 class="requirement">Requirements</h2>
        <textarea class="requirements" placeholder="Aspects" contenteditable ng-model="card.requirements"></textarea>
    </article>
</div>
```